# What methodology to adopt to support multilingual

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I have different applications which run on subscription base. The user come to my site and subscribe the application accordingly I provide then access to multiple applications from a single portal. Now i need to provide support to multiple languages. Initially we will provide support to three languages English, French and Spanish.

The technology we use is asp.net so to implement this feature we will use resource file but i am unsure what methodologies to follow

There are three options

1. The subscribed Client when they login first time i can provide default selection of supported languages and ask then to choose the language as per their preference and accordingly all users for the Client login will be presented the default language in their aspx page.
2. Provide the default language switcher in the portal from where the Client access all the applications and as per their selection the site default language in their aspx page will be switched.
3. Automatically redirect the site as per browser language.

The problem here i am not sure which methodology to adopt and which is most preferred methodology.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is purely an opinion as there is no right answer to your question.

I would present the option for language at login, but defaulted to the browser language if possible.

I would also likely make this setting accessible somewhere inside the application itself (in a settings page), if possible.

Since it is unlikely that the user will switch languages at any point in time (I assume), I would make this setting available as high up as possible. You mention a (single sign on?) portal, I would put it there, but again, have the option, just in case to change it somewhere in each app.